# Can I use Bing basemaps in the Google API?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to add a Bing Basemap layer to my Google Maps API Version 3 application?

I know you can add Bing basemaps in other APIs, such as ESRI and OpenLayers.  Just wondering if the Google API allows it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should check with lawyers, but I guess the answer is no, because both bing and Google put their logo at left bottom position and does not allow anything cover or hide it. Esri's logo is right side and they have special agreement with Bing, and openlayers is in different category.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't need to hide any logos.  If I were to consume a Bing basemap in the Google control, both Google and Bing would get paid accordingly.  Just need to know if it's possible.  Thanks.